# Click be ignored inside a touch binded element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, touch

I wrote an angular directive using mobile angular ui to test the touch thing like this:

```
<div touch-binded-element>
    <a href="something">html link</a>
</div>
```

Problem is when I debug the page in mobile mode, the html link inside the touch binded area can not be clicked any more. But everything works just fine in desktop mode. Is there any tricky tips should I pay attention when I develop mobile webpages?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by add only one line of code like this:

```
$touch.bind(element, {
    start: ...,
    move:  ...,
    end: function(touchInfo, e) {
        ...
        e.target.click();
    }
});
```

Just add the **e.target.click()** to the bottom of touchend function.